# Generation SHA-256 key for android app

Tags: android, sha, digest

whenever i'm trying to generate SHA-256 key i'm only getting MD5 key And SHA-1 key what should i do for getting SHA-256 key?

i have tried generating APK converting into ZIP file and then using CERT.RSA i tried to get key from CMD Using

command:C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -printcert -file C:\Users\vabs\Desktop\app-releaseSHA256Demo\META-INF\CERT.RSA

but i only got the response like :[image]

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore my_key.keystore -alias X -storepass Y -keypass Z. Shows both SHA1 and SHA256.

Comment: Elletlar, i tried but its not working it shows the same output which i have posted already.

Comment: Okay. Not sure. I'm on a much newer version. Could that make a difference? JDK can be updated here: [Update JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Comment: I downloaded 1.7.0 and created a key using: "keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-test.keystore -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000". But when I use "keytool -list -v" it shows: MD5, SHA1 and SHA256. I get the same output as you except that I have a line for SHA256...